# Store a Lua function?

Tags: c, function, lua

[Calling a Lua function](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_call) from C is fairly straight forward but is there a way to *store* a Lua function somewhere for later use?  I want to store user defined Lua functions passed to my C function for use on events, similar to how the [Connect function works in wxLua](http://wxlua.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

check the registry (`luaL_ref()`).  it manages a simple table that lets you store any Lua value (like the function), and refer to it from C by a simple integer.

Comment: Lua ref is just too cool - can't believe I've been using Lua all this time without knowing about this feature.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Building on Javier's answer, Lua has a special universally-accessible table called the registry, accessible through the C API using the pseudo-index `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX`. You can use the `luaL_ref` function to store any Lua value you like in the registry (including Lua functions) and receive back an integer that can be used to refer to it from C:

```
// Assumes that the function you want to store is on the top of stack L
int function_index = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is for your function to take a "name" and the lua function text. Then you create a table in the interpreter (if it doesn't exist) and then store the function in the table using the named parameter.

In your app just keep hold of a list of function names tied to each event. When the event fires just call all the functions from your table whose key matches the names in the list.

Comment: That functionality already exist and it's the Lua reference table as Javier said.

Comment: The problem with naming the functions in this case is that we want the user to be able to define multiple functions with essentially the same name - e.g. "onclick" for button1 is different than "onclick" for button2.